# Prestashop, Dropdowns bugueados

Tags: prestashop, prestashop1.7

Buenas tardes estimados,
Tengo una situación con Prestashop 1.7.5.1, cuando accedo a algunas secciones de módulos o cambios en los que se debe seleccionar un Dropdown me aparece como bugueado y no me deja escoger ninguna opción.

Ya he buscado en bastantes foros de Prestashop sobre esto pero no encuentro nada que me solucione.
Aclaro que esto tambien me pasaba con la version mas reciente 1.7.6.X

Adjunto unas imágenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien tuvo antes un problema así ya sea para cargar un tema por FTP o al agregar o configurar un modulo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solia tener ese mismo error, después de muchas semanas de lidear con eso al fin encontré que el problema, lo que pasa es que tu versión de PHP no va con tu versión de Prestashop. Entra a este link https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/system-requirements/ y en "PHP compatibility chart" esta sus respectivas versiones correctas de PHP para Prestashop. Espero que esto solucione tu problema, se que eso es realmente muy molesto...